How to manipulate lists in LaTeX? I want to get a value from a list based on its numerical index
I want to use the expl3 package to manipulate lists in LaTeX. My goal is to create an empty list called \mylist, fill it with values, and then retrieve a specific value based on a given numerical index, as explained here. The main difference is that I want to populate the list using a \foreach loop, rather than manually as shown in the example. Below is my minimal reproducible example (MRE):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \mylist
%\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \mylist {}
\newcommand\test[2]{\seq_item:Nn #2 {#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\mylist \\
\foreach \f in {0,...,10}{
    \f \\
    \xdef\mylist{\mylist,\f}
}
\mylist \\
\test{2}{\mylist} % "3" expected.
\test{5}{\mylist} % "6" expected.
\end{document}


Instead of printing the expected values 3 or 6, it prints the entire \mylist list. How can I achieve the desired result? Thanks in advance for your help.

Use \clist_item:Nn instead of \seq_item:Nn

welcome! please don't say \seq_new:N \mylist. it should be e.g. \seq_new:N \l_velandia_mylist_seq or \clist_new:N \l_velandia_mylist_clist or whatever. the l says the variable is local, velandia is the module name, mylist describes the purpose and clist or seq describes the type. all expl3 code should conform to the syntax to avoid the nightmare of conflicts we have in latex2.

it really doesn't make sense to mix \foreach with expl3 like this. expl3 has facilities for loops builtin. and sequences are not the same as comma-separated lists. but pgf can also handle (regular) comma-separated lists. so it is generally easier not to mix them except when you really need to as going back and forth creates its own problems.

use the right command to extend the sequence: \seq_put_right:Nn, see the documentation interface3.pdf.

why do you want \foreach here? rather than an L3 command? apart from looking odd, \foreach is tricky to use in code as it keeps each iteration in a group so any assignments you make in one step are lost at the next item

I suggest the listofitems package for creating and retrieving list items.

You don't need the \foreach command as the functionality is provided by expl3 commands. Also, please use proper naming conventions for variables. Here's an implementation using expl3 commands that achieves what you're after. Note that for some time now, you do not need to load expl3 explicitly as it's incorporated into the kernel.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_cristian_mylist_clist
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \listentry { m m }
  {
    \clist_item:cn {l_cristian_#2_clist} {#1}
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \printlist { O{,} m }
  {
    \clist_use:cn {l_cristian_#2_clist} { #1 }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \addtolist { m m }
  {
    \clist_put_right:cn {l_cristian_#1_clist} { #2 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\addtolist{mylist}{0,1,2}
\printlist{mylist}

\addtolist{mylist}{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
\printlist[; ]{mylist}

\listentry{2}{mylist}

\listentry{5}{mylist}

\end{document}


